# Where does the hybris generate war file,Cloud foundry cannot detect the war file when pushing to pcf

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-commerce-cloud

i am trying to deploy hybris cuppy project to cloud foundry,But when i try to push it.it says

ERR No container can run this application
OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase.

when i googled it i found it mostly occurs because if it couldnt detect the war file or jar file.Want to know where does hybris generate war file.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate war for cuppy extension by running from 'cuppy' directory:

```
ant build_war
```

Then check console output.